# The required resource (jsp) is not available when accessing a .jsf

Tags: jsf-2, jboss

I am new at JSF, so do not assume that it is not some dumb mistake.

I am deploying my webapp, from Eclipse Indigo into JBoss 6.1. I can check that the webapp is deployed in the server because an static index.html file works ok (and changes in it are reflected via web browser).

I have a JSF2 Facelet in pages/NewRequest.jsf, which very little logic (in fact it is plain XHTML):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:body>
Hola mundo again....
</h:body>
</html>
```

My web.xml is the following (I checked that the FaceServlet is configured)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee web-app_3_0.xsd">
<display-name>GesMan</display-name>
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>NewRequest.jsf</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

It all looks legit for me, but when I try to access the JSF I only get a 404 error page that tells me that a JSP with the same name that my JSP does not exist. No error is shown neither in the console nor in the server.log file

Could you tell me what I am doing wrong, or how can I get a more specific error information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file extension of the actual view file should represent the view technology used (e.g. `.xhtml` or `.jsp`), not the JSF mapping (e.g. `.jsf`). You should have a `pages/NewRequest.xhtml`, not a `pages/NewRequest.jsf`.

Your other problem is that the welcome file can't represent a mapped (virtual) filename, but must represent an actual filename. So you need `NewRequest.xhtml` there. But this in turn requires you that you map the `FacesServlet` on exactly that URL pattern.

So, all with all, just simplify the `web.xml` as follows:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>NewRequest.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

This way you can continue using `.xhtml` in URLs without fiddling with virtual URLs.

Comment: Ok, it was the .xhtml issue. I looked at the (Eclipse generated) web.xml file and assumed that the mapping meant that I had to name my files like that (the change in the welcome-file was just a trial). Thanks very much.